# Hibernate LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a web service which is essentially a wrapper for a DAO.  I am calling the web service/DAO to request a collection of entities.

The "parent" entity class contains a collection of "child" entity objects, i.e. a one-to-many relationship.  The DAO method call which fetches the "parent" entity collection (i.e. myDAO.findAll()) returns with no problem, however the final result of the web service call is this exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Station.observations, no session or session was closed
```

Some background information:

I have two entities, Station and Observations.  A Station entity (the "parent") contains a collection of Observations objects (the "children").

The DAO class for Station entities, StationDao has the following code for the method being called, findAll():

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private Class<T> persistentClass;

public List<T> findAll()
{
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + persistentClass.getName()).list();
}
```

In this case I'm not interested in the collection of children (observations) related to the parents (stations) being fully fetched before the collection of parents is returned.  However it seems that there is some attempt being made to fully fetch these child (observations) objects before returning the collection of parent (station) objects in the response, and this is failing because the original session is no longer available.

Can anyone suggest how I would get around this error?  Perhaps there's a way to persist the session over the life of the request?

Thanks in advance for your help!

--James

Comment: search for the "open session in view" pattern

Comment: You could try to fetch the Observations eager but if you want to keep the lazy loading you have to ensure the session is alive. I'd suggest you search for 'Unit of Work' and Transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am using the approach suggested here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessioninView, but unfortunately when I get into the filter code to get the current session I get an error telling me "No Hibernate Session bound to thread".  My DAO classes are annotated with @Transactional and I have set the <tx:annotation-driven> in my Spring application context to the Hibernate transaction manager.  Can anyone suggest what else I should look at as a possible cause of my error?

Answer (score 0):

I have had situation when "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role" was caused by using persistent objects after calling

```
HibernateTemplate.clear()
```

Even though the session was still active, the old objects were not. One possible way of solving the problem was to get the objects from session again.